# php __DIR__ not executing consistently

Tags: php, wordpress, include

This code works perfectly.  IF i first have an error in my form - in this case using an email to register, that has already been used.  The error message is displayed in register.php.  Then if I correct the error, the Include **DIR** works fine, and the login.php page is displayed.  However, if I use an email to register that has not been used (meaning, no errors in my form the first time), it simply ignores the include **DIR** . '/templates/login.php' and stops.  No errors in the debug log, just my logging.  The user is added.

The form is a simple post, with one input, the email address, which i use for registering a user.  the logging shows the resolved directory correct in both instances, which looks like this
C:\wamp\www\bglswp\wp-content\plugins\bgls-players/templates/login.php

The include **DIR** for the form register.php works consistently.

Been pulling my challenged hairline out for 2 days ;-/.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
public function register_player() {

    // rem to secure form,, hidden + nonce

    if ( $_POST ) {
        $errors = array();

        // security validations
        $this-> bgls_validate_post();

        $user_login = ( isset ( $_POST['email'] ) ?  $_POST['email'] : '' );
        $user_email = ( isset ( $_POST['email'] ) ? $_POST['email'] : '' );

        // Validating user data, leaving the duplicative logic until i see email as user works
        if ( empty( $user_login ) ) {
            array_push( $errors, 'Please enter a username.' );
        }    
        if ( empty( $user_email ) ) {
            array_push( $errors, 'Please enter e-mail.' );
        }

        //make sure email is valid email and not previously used
        if ( !empty($user_email) && !is_email( $user_email ) ) {
        array_push( $errors, 'Please enter valid email.') ; }
            elseif ( email_exists( $user_email ) ){
                array_push( $errors, 'User with this email already registered.');
           }   
        // make sure no funny stuff in the email  
        // then see make sure not previously used       
        $strict = 'true';   
        $sanitized_user_login = sanitize_user( $user_login, $strict );

        if ( empty( $sanitized_user_login ) || !validate_username($user_login ) ){
            array_push( $errors, 'Invalid username.' );   
            }
        elseif ( username_exists( $sanitized_user_login ) ) {
            array_push( $errors, 'Username already exists.' );
        }

        // if no errors  generate a password,  and insert the user in the wp db
        if ( empty( $errors ) ) {

            //$user_pass = wp_generate_password();
            $user_pass = 'password1' ;  // test code  remove this

            $user_id = wp_insert_user( array
                    ('user_login' => $sanitized_user_login, 
                    'user_email' => $user_email,
                    'role' => 'player',  // users can only register as players  
                    'user_pass' => $user_pass)     
                    );
                    $this-> log_hra($user_id . 'after wp insert 1');  // added logging

            if ( !$user_id ) {

                array_push( $errors, 'Registration failed.' ); 
            }   else    {

                    $activation_code = 'player';
                    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'activation_code', $activation_code );
                    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'activation_status', 'inactive' );

                    //wp_new_user_notification( $user_id, $user_pass, $activation_code );
                    $success_message = "Registration completed successfully. Please check your email for activation link.";
                    }               

            if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) {
                $this-> log_hra( __DIR__ . '/templates/login.php');  //added logging 
                include __DIR__ . '/templates/login.php';
                exit;
             }
        }  //   /if empty errors    

    }   //  /if post

    // if the user is first registering, present a blank register template
    if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) {
        include __DIR__ . '/templates/register.php';
    exit;
    }
}  // end register_player
```

Comment: What exactly does not work ? What do you expect ?

Comment: the  include __DIR__ . '/templates/login.php does not display the login.php page, only in the instance where there is not an error in the form the first time.  The login.php is displayed I have an error in my form, correct it, then re-submit the form.  thanks.

Comment: i cant really make out what you are describing! Your post says one thing and comments something different, the code is semi clear but there are custom functions in there so no-one can test.. Maybe try and describe a bit better and remove the code not relevant to the question? (make sure you test it locally to ensure the code edit still causes an issue) It sounds like $errors is not empty on one of the conditions you described

Answer (score 0):

You missed the `else` when there is errors:

```
        // ...
        }  //   end if empty errors

        // else errors
        else {
            // This is the missing part
            include __DIR__ . '/templates/register.php';
            exit;
        }

    }   //  end if post

    // else no post
    // if the user is first registering, present a blank register template
    if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) {
        include __DIR__ . '/templates/register.php';
        exit;
    }
}  // end register_player
```

The `else` is not mandatory as you end the previous `if` with `exit`.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Heah, however that is not it.  The errors always post correctly, it is the success path that executes include __DIR__ . '/templates/login.php' that is at issue.  The success path code is executed whenever it is supposed to, (I can tell from my added logging), it seems to ignore the include ;-(   (I tried adding yours anyway, and the result is the same, it just catches the error path differently)

Comment: Also removed the if ( !is_user_logged in and moved the code under the $success_message; it didn't work either, (not that i expected it to)